# How to extract row based on list of hex interval with awk?

Tags: awk, unicode, hex

#### Input file

```
U+3400  qiū
U+3401  tiàn
…
U+4E00  yī
U+4E01  dīng
…
U+2B5E7 sù
U+2B5EE huáng
```

#### List of intervals

List of unicode codepoint

```
4E00-9FFF
3400-4DBF
20000-2A6DF
2A700-2B73F
2B740-2B81F
2B820-2CEAF
F900-FAFF
```

#### Question

How do I print only the row that belong to one of the hexadecimal interval?

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input plus what you've tried so far. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk -F'[+ -]' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a {print $0}' f2 f1
U+3400  qiū
U+4E00  yī
```

Here f2 is List of intervals.

Answer (score 0):

#### chinese.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

BEGIN {
    split(toggleValues, boundaries, ",")
    start=0
    end=start+1
}

/U\+/ && /kMandarin/ {
    row = toHex($1);
    if (toHex(boundaries[start]) <= row && row <= toHex(boundaries[end])) print $1"\t"$3
    if (row >= toHex(boundaries[end])) {start+=2; end=start+1}
}

function toHex(field) { return strtonum("0x" substr(field, 3)) };
```

#### Usage

```
toggleValues="U+4E00,U+9FFF,U+3400,U+4DBF,U+20000,U+2A6DF,U+2A700,U+2B73F,U+2B740,U+2B81F,U+2B820,U+2CEAF,U+F900,U+FAFF"
awk -f src/chinese.awk \
    -v toggleValues="$toggleValues" src/Unihan_Readings.txt 
> src/codepoint-ruby.tsv
```